# JavaScript array flatting

Tags: javascript, arrays

i need to get every unique color in the array below fit in one single array

```js
const colours = [{
    mood: "happy",
    fish: "robin",
    colours: ["blue", "green"]
  },
  {
    mood: "tired",
    fish: "panther",
    colours: ["green", "black", "orange", "blue"]
  },
  {
    mood: "sad",
    fish: "goldfish",
    colours: ["green", "red"]
  }
];
console.log(colours.map(e => {
  let flatArray = e.colours.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
    return acc.concat(curVal)
  }, []);
  return flatArray
}))
```

It currently outputs:

```
[
   [ 'blue', 'green' ],
   [ 'green', 'black', 'orange', 'blue' ],
   [ 'green', 'red' ]
]
```

Comment: It is nice that you provide the output for the code, but more important is what you would *need* the output to be.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your output should look like. Should it be `[ 'green', 'black', 'orange', 'blue', 'red' ],`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `map` and also `reduce`

Comment: You need `flatMap` and `Set`.

Comment: To clarify, we wonder for example if you want multiple "green" or a single in the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but this will create a single array of unique colors.

```
let unique = [...new Set(colours.flatMap(c => c.colours))]
```

`flatMap()` allows us to cycle through and create a one dimensional array of the existing colours, while `[...new Set(array)]` lets us strip out duplicates

```js
colours = [{
    mood: "happy",
    fish: "robin",
    colours: ["blue", "green"]
  },
  {
    mood: "tired",
    fish: "panther",
    colours: ["green", "black", "orange", "blue"]
  },
  {
    mood: "sad",
    fish: "goldfish",
    colours: ["green", "red"]
  }
]

let unique = [...new Set(colours.flatMap(c => c.colours))]
console.log(unique)
```

Comment: If this is the output desired, this is a really elegant way and not too hard to grok.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need reduce. You can simply pass all the `colours` arrays to `concat()` with argument spreading.

```
let colours_array = [].concat(...colours.map(el => el.colours));
```

Then see [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array/9229821#9229821) for how to get just the unique colours from this result.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let colours = [{
        mood: "happy",
        fish: "robin",
        colours: ["blue", "green"]
    },
    {
        mood: "tired",
        fish: "panther",
        colours: ["green", "black", "orange", "blue"]
    },
    {
        mood: "sad",
        fish: "goldfish",
        colours: ["green", "red"]
    }];


let distinct =(value,index,self)=>{return self.indexOf(value)===index;};

console.log(colours.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
        return acc.concat(curVal.colours)
    }, []).filter(distinct));
```